# select all latest indexed data from sphinx search

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I am new in Sphinx SE with PHP sphinx client. I have two query, I have tried hard but failed.

a) Am trying to get some result from sphinx like which is in SQL (`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC`). 
Example :

```
$results = $client->Query('*', 'posts');
```

in sphinx.conf file I have added `enable_star = 1` in Index section

b) Also am trying to index number of comment against the blog, failed to write .conf for this.

sphinx.conf:

```
source blog
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        = root
    sql_db          = myblog
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query = SELECT id, title, content, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publish_date) AS publish_date, author_id FROM posts

    sql_attr_uint = author_id 
    sql_field_string = title
    sql_field_string = content

    sql_attr_multi = uint category_id from query; \
                    SELECT post_id, category_id FROM posts_categories

    sql_attr_timestamp = publish_date

    sql_query_info  = SELECT id, title FROM posts WHERE ID=$id
}


index posts
{
    source          = blog
    path            = C:\sphinx\data\blog
    docinfo         = extern
    charset_type    = sbcs
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 32M
}

searchd
{
    listen = 9312
    log = c:\sphinx\log\searchd.log
    query_log = c:\sphinx\log\query.log
    max_children = 30
    pid_file = c:\sphinx\log\searchd.pid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to answer that question, because the topic is far to broad and there are
lots of things which might have gone wrong: mysql, mysql-config, sphinx, sping-config, the table structure, the queries, etc.

For instance you do SQL: `FROM table` and then Spinx: `blogs`. Be exact.

Post your configs!

I would suggest to read these two tutorials, on how to get a sphinx search working:

- http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/01/11/sphinx-search-engine-and-php-installation-indexing/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/

Comment: I have added the .conf.